# Want to use NSKeyed Archiever n NSKeyedUnarcheiver in array and an object

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to use NSKeyedArchiever to store values in an array which contains an object of a class which has five attributes in it.But i am not able to store the data in one single location for multiple times using NSData or NSArray.
For example-

I have a class named as car which has five attributes namely model,make,year,carnumber and color.I have an array which stores car object in a single unit in one index.I am trying to use NSKeyedArchiever n NSKeyedUnarchiever to do this step.Firtly i use NSKeyed archiever to store the values to class car variables and then i want to store it in an array.But i am not able to do that .Can you please help me with the code.I am not able to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post the code you already tried or the errors you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

as i know you have to use NSCoding to store custom objects.

as in my example i have a class Game and i am encoding and decoding it with this NSCoding methods

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:turnTime] forKey:@"turnTime"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:time] forKey:@"extra"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:saved] forKey:@"saved"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:dragon forKey:@"dragon"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:playerJokers forKey:@"playerJokersKey"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    turnTime=[[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"turnTime"] integerValue];
    dragon=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"dragon"];
    time=[[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"extra"] boolValue];
    saved=[[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"saved"] boolValue];
    playerJokers=[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"playerJokersKey"];
    return self;

}
```

to save gamedata

```
-(void)saveGameData
{
    NSLog(@"saveGameData");

    NSUserDefaults * userdefaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSData * gameData=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];

    [userdefaults setObject:gameData forKey:@"gameKey"];

    [userdefaults synchronize];
}
```

as seen this method; you can convert your custom class to NSData and add it to the NSArray.

when you want to use it; restore array and you have an array of including car data.

when i want to use saved data

```
Game * savedGame=[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:gameData];
```